# Visual Studio Ignore .vs

Tags: git, visual-studio, bitbucket, gitignore

So, I tried making a new project and using BitBucket. I wanted to push my newly created project to the repository. However somehow my `.vs` and my `packages` folders got commited as well. I was too late with adding my `.gitignore` file and also It still commits the `.vs` file. Could anyone help me please?
Thank you

[image: vscode pic]

How can I remove those files from my repository and prevent this from happening in the future?

Comment: Two things before each commit: 1. don't blindly `add` everything, but review and choose 2. anything showing up as an option that should not be added, add to `.gitignore` (you'll find these in step #1)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's a proper answer.

1. Add `.vs` to `.gitignore` this will prevent it getting re-added again.
2. Remove `.vs` from the git index but leave it on your file system. `git rm -r --cached .vs`
3. Commit your updated `.gitignore`. `git commit .gitignore`.
4. Push your changes.

Comment: `.vs` is a directory, so you need the `-r` option to remove it recursively: `git rm -r --cached .vs`

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I've updated it.

Comment: As a Mercurial user it took me a long time to realise adding something to .gitignore doesn't automatically treat those files as nonexistent to Git. In Mercurial, if you add something to .hgignore, even if you had previously committed those files, they now appear to Mercurial as if you had deleted them from disk. A much better system IMO, no need to manually remove the files.